# Demurrage vs inflation

Tags: currency, inflation

Is demurrage and inflation the same?
If both are at 1% a day and today I have $100, tomorrow:
 - Under demurrage I'll have $99
 - Under inflation I'll have $100, but that $100 will be worth only 99 of yesterday's dollars.

Either way, I end up with $99 in wealth.

So is there a difference between demurrage and inflation in their **effect** (end result)? Or is there a flaw with my thinking?

**EDIT**
I'm not looking for an answer constrained to the example in my question. I'm interested in the question of inflation vs demurrage from the **macro**economic perspective. What would our economy be like if our money had demurrage instead of inflation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a difference. If you've borrowed $100, then under inflation your salary will (presumably) increase, and tomorrow your debt will only be worth $99. But under demurrage, you'll still owe $100.